# Limit Lebesgues Integral

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^3 f(x)=1$, and $f(x)$ is Lebesgue measurable, does  $\lim_{c \to \infty} c\int_c^\infty (x-c)f(x) \, dx$ exist or not? If it exist what is the value? I have guessed a value $\frac{1}{2}$ by just replacing the $f(x)$ with $\frac{1}{x^{3}}$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: $\frac {1-\epsilon} {x^{3}} \leq f(x) \leq \frac {1+\epsilon} {x^{3}}$ if $x>c$ and $c$ is sufficiently large.